# Selenium code not executing after driver.get

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a website.I used driver,get() to access the page and did a couple of actions.Next I had to navigate to a certain page in that website and used driver.get() to access this. On executing the script works till that part,post this it simply stops and does not event do a print statment.At the end I get a timeout exception.I am not able to figure out where it is failing.

````
```code to automate which works well until here```
guid="48bc1201-3929-42af-85cf-50e89b53a800"
#guid=guid

url=baseurl+"#/loan/{"+ str(guid) + "}/summary"

print("qqw" + url)
driver.get(url)

#print functionality also does not happen.Basically the code freezes

print("next execution")
````

PS: the portion in code ***code to automate which works well until here*** indicates that I used all functionalities until here and they were working.Also in the last driver.get() the user is navigated to the required page.After this the script kind of pauses.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In my setup, `driver.get(URL)` fails randomly from time to time.

To detect a successful page load or to force a timeout to `driver.get(URL)`, I employ the following solution and it works for me:

```
driver.set_page_timeout(n)
driver.set_script_timeout(n)
loading_finished = 0                    # URL not loaded
loading_attempts = 0                    # Count loading attempts
while loading_finished = 0:             # Enter loop 
    try:                         
        if loading_attempts > 5:        # Threshold for loading attempts
             print "URL loading failed"
             break                      # Too many loading attempts - exit loop
        else:
             website = driver.get(URL)  # Try to load URL
             loading_finished = 1       # URL loaded successfully - exit loop
             print "URL loading worked"
    except:
           loading_attempts += 1        # Loading failed - count failed attempt and retry
else:
     process_URL(driver, URL)           # Do your magic
```

Comment: no the driver.get worked and I saw the new page also...after that execution got paused and after sometime saw a timeout exception.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output. If my answer helped you, please accept it

Comment: I had properly added the description...please see it.

Comment: put my code into a seperate def, and catch the timeout exception. You can save the URL that did not work in a seperate list and loop through the list again