# Code does not always get past driver.get(...) using chromedriver with Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python program that scrapes https://performance.morningstar.com/fund/tax-analysis.action?t=AGRYX&region=usa&culture=en-US. It works much of the time, but maybe around 1/3 of the time my code execution does not get passed

```
driver.get('https://performance.morningstar.com/fund/tax-analysis.action?t=' + ws.cell(i,2).value + '&region=usa&culture=en-US')
```

where `ws.cell(i,2).value` is just a ticker symbol inside an excel spreadsheet.

No error is thrown. It simply does not get passed this line. The browser fully loads the page I want it to, it just goes no further (again, no error is thrown).

I have added these options hoping for the best

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\my\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

I don't know if it matters, but I do see a warning in the address bar that says the website is "!Not secure", which seems odd to me because I would have though morningstar would go to great lengths to make sure they were providing secure content. For kicks, I did set my chrome options to accept insecure content for this site but it did not make a difference.

How can I continue my code execution beyond this line? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168297/selenium-code-not-executing-after-driver-get) is similar to mine but since no error is thrown, the answer given does not work for me.

Comment: What happens after the driver.get?

Comment: It seems to not matter. Whatever code I place under it doesn't get reached.